# jnlp: Reading properties file from server

Tags: java, jnlp, database-connectivity

I am launching application through jnlp, where i need to read the database configuration from server (Tomcat). Is it possible to connect to the host address or can i read properties file before jnlp launching the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect to the host address..?

Yes.  Even a sand-boxed JWS app. can 'phone home'.

Form an URL relative to the codebase of the application (is usually easiest).  To gain the codebase, see [`BasicService.getCodeBase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#getCodeBase%28%29).  Here is a [demo. of the `BasicService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs) (it includes source and build files).